# Сертификат для https для localhost

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, https

Создал пустой проект с веб-приложение в VS 2015, в настройках указал `SSL Enabled: True`. Запустил и увидел ошибку в Chrome 58, что подключение не защищено.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя сертификат вроде как действительный. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая конкретно ошибка выходит? ее можно увидеть в developer tools (F12) во вкладке Security

Comment: @Ruslan_K обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome Начиная с версии 58 требует чтобы поле сертификата SAN (Subject Alternative Name) было заполнено.

Подробнее в статье [Chrome Deprecates Subject CN Matching](https://textslashplain.com/2017/03/10/chrome-deprecates-subject-cn-matching/)

Создать сертификат и заполнить Subject Alternative Name можно используя OpenSSL как показано в [ответе](https://serverfault.com/a/301852):

Для тех кто использует ЦС предприятия или автономный ЦС запрос сертификата можно сделать через остнастку "сертификаты" как показано статье [How to Request a Certificate With a Custom Subject Alternative Name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625722(v=ws.10))